# Link that automatically fills a field on the target page

Tags: opencart

How can I construct a URL that will automatically fill in a field on the target page?, 
I tried already `https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?route=account/register?name=firstname` to fill first name on registration form, but for opencart it won't work, so please tell me what I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file:

```
catalog\controller\account\register.php
```

Find:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['firstname'])) {
    $data['firstname'] = $this->request->post['firstname'];
} else {
    $data['firstname'] = '';
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['firstname'])) {
    $data['firstname'] = $this->request->post['firstname'];
} else if (isset($this->request->get['name'])) {
    $data['firstname'] = $this->request->get['name'];
} else {
    $data['firstname'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Still won't work, because opencart already have route url. Can you double check it please?

Comment: Error
php 404 The page you requested cannot be found.

Comment: wow thanks I changed to & and it really works. Thanks a lot buddy.